# Problem Hive Metastore with Apache BigTop on Centos7

Tags: apache-spark, exception, hive, hive-metastore, bigtop

I have installed Hive, Hadoop and Spark with Apache BigTop 3.2.1 on Centos 7. I have executed all the commands to start Hadoop and Yarn. When I run hive from the console, it apparently starts without errors but after a few seconds it shows a MetaException error. Afterwards the console appears in hive> mode but when writing a simple SHOW DATABASES it still gives the same error. What do I have to configure? Should I change the Hive metastore?

I tried to change some lines in hive-site.xml but got the same error